# Как отобразить картинку в Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Проблема заключается в том, что php не работает в форме, и я не могу получить директорию темы с помощью get_template_directory_uri . Как заставить php работать, если он размещен в коде формы?

Comment: Вообщето никак, сдесь более целесообразный выход - добавить в форму свой класс, к нему на бекграунд прописать нужную картинку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести что-то внутри формы CF7, надо создать свой тег. Нижеприведённый код надо разместить в `functions.php`. Он создаёт тег img.

```
/**
 * Return image for CF7 tag.
 *
 * @param $tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_form_tag_img_handler( $tag ) {
    return '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $tag['options'][0] . '">';
}

/**
 * Hook to add custom 'img' tag to CF7.
 * Usage in CF7: [acf source]
 */
function custom_add_form_tag_img() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'img', 'custom_add_form_tag_img_handler' );
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_img' );
```

Использовать тег в форме надо примерно таким образом:

```
[text lastname  placeholder "Фамилия"] [text your-name placeholder "Имя"] 

[img roses.jpg]

[submit "Зарегистрироваться"]
```

Между инпутом и кнопкой будет выведена ваша картинка.

Answer (score 0):

PHP не будет работать в редакторе CF7. Но можешь попробовать запихнуть свой PHP скрипт в шорткод (создаешь шорткод в файле functions.php) и вставляешь его в форму. Так должно сработать

Comment: Нет, это не работает