# Вывести название страницы в Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

Как в CF7 вывести в тему письма название страницы? Не весь URL, а только название  страницы, с которой отправляется форма. Сейчас сделано тегом `[_url]`, но надо только название, без всего URL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Согласно правилам, картинки должны в теле вопроса. Я поправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте тег `[_post_title]`.

Перечень всех тегов [здесь](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/).

Comment: [_post_title]  не работает

Comment: А что это за тип контента, где у вас форма - страница, пост?

Comment: Тип записи Страницы

Comment: Ничего подобного. Этот тег работает. Я только что протестировал: https://monosnap.com/file/TIyl72vPW8WTr9MWtjmek71oa78kaQ

Comment: на моем сайте не работает. Как еще можно передать в тему письма данные ?

Comment: > На моем сайте не работает < - ищите причину: отключайте плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную. Сам по себе ответ правильный.

Comment: Даже если вы создадите собственный тег в CF7, он тоже может не работать.

Comment: Вот мой ответ о создании кастомных тегов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874469/220220